# Main report does not load if the subreport is blank

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on a Crystal report and there is a subreprot for that. For some of the customer there is no data in the table sub report is using. So for those customer the main report comes as blank..

Is there a way to fix it ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Could possibly be a problem with your subreport links.

2) Or the JOINS in you main report. You must be using a INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN. Confirm that all the links are correct. If possible SQL profile the report when run and have a look at your query.